# cannot unpack non-iterable PathCollection object

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0,500)
ax.set_ylim(0,500)
scatter, = ax.scatter(x_arr,y_arr)
plt.show()
```

### In the scatter statement, the program is rising this error. I don't understand what may be the problem.

```
---
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-b70b84828456> in <module>
      6 ax.set_xlim(0,500)
      7 ax.set_ylim(0,500)
----> 8 scatter, = ax.scatter(x_arr,y_arr)
      9 plt.show()

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable PathCollection object
```

Comment: `ax.plot()` returns a **list** of ` Line2D` objects. It is a list because `plot` allows to draw multiple curves at the same time.  To get the first `Linde2D` of a list with one element, people use a comma: `line, = ax.plot()`. It is similar to `lines = ax.plot(); line = lines[0]`. `ax.scatter()`, however, doesn't return a list, just a `PathCollection` which you can't assign that way.

Comment: Thankyou, Also can you suggest any way I scatter plot to return a list

Comment: Scatter plot will not return a list. But the PathCollection it does return, contains a list of all the points. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/collections_api.html) for a list of functions (get/set) that could be called on such a collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chage 4th line to:

```
scatter = ax.scatter(x_arr,y_arr)
```

It'll solve your issue.

**scatter just returns a object.**

Comment: Thanks. Was copying an example that used `line, = ax.plot(...)`. @JohanC's comment above was also helpful.

Comment: May I ask, for example, what `curve, = ax.plot(x,y)` return?

Comment: @WeiShanLee According to [Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html), `ax.plot` will return a list of `Line2D` objects. These objects are matplotlib [line](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) objects. Depending on the number of lines you plot within a call, the returned number of `Line2D` objects differs. In your case `curve` is a `Line2D`.
You can also have something like `curve1, curve2 = ax.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)`.